# How can I create exceptions in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use friendly urls:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ pages/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

But at the same time, I want `/forum/folder` to be excluded from that rule in the `.htaccess` file.

How can I do that?

Comment: `A-Za-z0-9_` is `\w`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ pages/$1.php [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> ... I want `/forum/folder` to be excluded

Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$`) already excludes the URL-path `/forum/folder`, since the pattern does not permit a slash (directory separator) in the middle of the URL-path; only at end.

So, if `/forum/folder` is still being routed then *something else* is doing this. If there is an additional `.htaccess` in this subdirectory (assuming it's a physical directory) that uses mod_rewrite then you could encounter conflicts.

---

Otherwise, there are a few ways to make an exception:

**#1 - Exclude All Files and Folders:** If you specifically want to exclude all files and folders from being rewritten (assuming `/forum/folder` is a physical directory) then you can specifically check for this and only process the `RewriteRule` if the URL-path does not map to a file or directory. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

The `QSA` flag is not required here, since the query string from the request is appended by default. Only if you are specifying a query string in the *substitution* and you need to merge this with the query string on the request do you need this flag. And as Deadooshka mentioned in comments, `\w` is a short hand character for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so this simplifies the regex a bit.

---

**#2 - Exclude Rule:** Use a rule at the start of your file that matches the path you want to exclude and simply stop processing. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/folder - [L]
```

If the requested URL starts with `/forum/folder` then stop here and don't process further rules.

---

**#3 - Negated Condition:** Include a *negated* conditon (`RewriteCond` directive) in the rule itself. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/folder
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

This will only process the `RewriteRule` if the requested URL does not start with `/forum/folder`. The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex.

---

**#4 - Negative Lookahead in the `RewriteRule` pattern:** If you only have one rule and one URL you want to exclude from this rule then you could use a *negative lookahead* in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (regex). For example, to exclude the URL `/forum` in the above directive:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!forum)[\w-]+)/$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

The `(?!forum)` is the negative lookahead.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to your question. If you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file then add your entire `.htaccess` file - there could be a conflict. Also, do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Comment: There may be something else going on here since your existing directive would already exclude a URL-path of the form `/forum/folder`. If there is an additonal `.htaccess` file in this subdirectory then that could be the reason why it's not working. I've updated my answer.